# Access request variables in iFrame

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am trying to build a multiplayer game as a Facebook app, So, in this I give one player a link , which he shares with his friends , so that they can play together, 
FB apps link are of the url type

```
https://apps.facebook.com/app-name/
```

Say someone shares a link

```
https://apps.facebook.com/app-name/?game=key
```

Now the real problem occurs, how would the app which is currently running as an iframe, would access the parent windows game variable?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `app_data` parameter. Have a lookt at these links:

- [Facebook documentation Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)
- [Facebook iFrame Tab Applications](http://acknowledgement.co.uk/post/First-Look-Tutorial-Facebook-iFrame-Tab-Applications/244)

So, basically, the app_data parameter will be passed through in the `signed_request` to your app within the iFrame. For this to work you have to json_encode the parameter. So, in your example case:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/?app_data={'game': 'key'}
```

and finally url encoded:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/?app_data=7B%27game%27%3A+%27key%27%7D
```

to gain access, you have to read out the signed_request (example with PHP):

```
$app_data = json_decode($signed_request["app_data"]);
$additional = $app_data['additional'];
```

Comment: From the documentation this works in tab applications, but not canvas apps. I'm trying to do the same thing and this example is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Basically instead of using a question mark just add it to the URL:

https://apps.facebook.com/app-name/game/key

Just make sure to setup your app to handle things at:

https://yourdomain.com/canvas-url/game/key

I posted a more in-depth answer to this problem over at a duplicate question:

[$_GET on facebook iframe app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414853/get-on-facebook-iframe-app/7734877#7734877)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, the answer is pretty simple:

```
https://apps.facebook.com/app-name/?myvalue=12
```

On Page Apps you can only use "app_data" as parameter, but on Canvas Apps you just use your own parameters and you can get them with $_REQUEST['myvalue'] or $_GET['myvalue']:

```
array(2) { ["myvalue"]=> string(2) "12" ["signed_request"]=> string(427) "..." }
```